# Move position of choice field beside DateTime field

Tags: date-time, choice-field, move

please help me. I've got custom New event formular and I need arrange fields in it. I need move choice field "Termin od" beside Date&Time field named "Čas začatia", moreover how can I hide name of this choice field "Termin od" without hiding choices? If I use jQuery, it hides the field completely (Name and choices).

Got anybody some ideas of css or jQuery?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using Sharepoint list forms - Below Jquery code should move the choice field

**Code for DispForm.aspx**
        $("a[name='SPBookmark_Identifier']").closest("td").next("td").appendTo($("a[name='SPBookmark_Title']").closest("tr"));
    $("a[name='SPBookmark_Identifier']").closest("tr").hide();

- Replace *Identifier* with the internal name of your *Termin od* field
- Replace *Title* with the internal name of your *Čas začatia* field

**Code for EditForm.aspx & NewForm.aspx**

```
$(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").appendTo($(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(1)")[0]); $(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(2)").hide()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is my code: 

<script>
// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a[name='Term_x00ed_n_x0020_od']").closest("td").next("td").appendTo($("a[name='EventDate']").closest("tr"));
$("a[name='Term_x00ed_n_x0020_od']").closest("tr").hide();    
});
</script>

Comment: you need to use  SPBookmark_YOURINTERNALCOLNAME  in your Jquery selector. Such as SPBookmark_EventDate and SPBookmark_Term_x00e‌​d_n_x0020_od

Comment: I used this option too, but there's no effect. 
Here is code:
 <script>
// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a[name='SPBookmark_Term_x00ed_n_x0020_od']").closest("td").next("td").appendTo($("a[name='SPBookmark_EventDate']").closest("tr"));
$("a[name='SPBookmark_Term_x00ed_n_x0020_od']").closest("tr").hide();    
});
</script>

Comment: sorry my mistake! this code will work on the display form. I have added code for the Edit form to my answer which you can use as a reference.

Comment: You will need JQuery for this code to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44042/discussion-between-david-repka-and-harryb).

Comment: Thank you. Which term I need to replace in your code with my InternalFieldName?

Comment: Code for edit and new form doesnt require any field names. We are only selecting the TR elements. Look here for a reference - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Create new list form by using Sharepoint Designer and edit form html without using additional scripts and styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution code:

`<script language="javascript" src="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SiteAssets/code/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)").appendTo($(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)")[0]);
$(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(2)").appendTo($(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)")[1]);
$(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1)").hide();
$(".ms-formtable").find("tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(1)").hide();
});
</script>`

Thanks a lot to HarryB.